# Login Link Authentication doesn't work for me

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I am trying to implement [Login Link Authentication](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/login_link.html). Unfortunately, I am stuck with it. When I am moving to the generated link I am getting the next exception:

> InvalidLoginLinkAuthenticationException: Login link could not be
> validated

authentication doesn't work too: I can't visit secured area (*IS_AUTHENTICATED*). What I am doing wrong? Thanks!

**security.yaml**

```yaml
security:
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: users_in_memory

            login_link:
                check_route: login_check
                signature_properties: [ 'id' ]

    access_control:
        - { path: '/secured_area', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED }
```

**LoginController.php**

```php
class LoginController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route( '/login_check', name: 'login_check' )]
    public function loginCheck()
    {
        throw new \LogicException( 'This code should never be reached' );
    }

    #[Route( '/login', name: 'login' )]
    public function login( UserRepository $users, EntityManagerInterface $em,
                           LoginLinkHandlerInterface $loginLinkHandler, AuthenticationUtils $helper )
    {
        $userExisted = $users->findOneBy( [ 'id' => 771492419 ] );
        $loginLinkDetails = $loginLinkHandler->createLoginLink( $userExisted );
        $loginLink = $loginLinkDetails->getUrl();
        echo '<pre>' . $helper->getLastAuthenticationError() . '<br></pre>';
        return new Response( "<a href='{$loginLink}'>Click to authorize</a>" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to login normally via a form or whatever?

Comment: Generated login links are intended to be sent to the user and then to be clicked on.  All you are doing is returning it as a Response.  Not sure what you expect that to do.  If you want to immediately 'click' the link then you might try returning a RedirectRepsonse.  No idea if that will work.  Otherwise I would suggest following the example in the docs, get that working then adjust it to suit your needs.

Comment: Sorry to keep spamming but it seems like you just want the user to be logged in automatically?  If so then have you considered just [directly logging the user in](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#login-programmatically)? Using `$security->login($user)`

Comment: Cerad, thanks for your response! I just trying to make work the auth mechanic on my dev server, so that I need nothing than the link returned

Comment: Sure, I can use method login to auth manually. But that's strange I can't make work the Login Link Authentication example from official docs. May be I've overlooked some tiny, but important detail...

Comment: I still don't understand what `return new Response( $loginLink );` is supposed to do.  Do you get a blank page with the link in your browser and then click on it?

Comment: I just follow the link. It's a dev server, I am trying to make it works. There's no real users that needed cute stylized form or something.

Comment: In the slightly modified example you posted on the Symfony Discussion board you defined an entity user provider but you still have the firewall using the in_memory_user provider.  Pretty sure that is not going to help.

Comment: Yes, this was the case - I discovered it today morning :) But I think will be great if you post the solution as an answer so that I can choose it as a solution

Comment: Glad you got it working.  I'll let you post an answer showing the final working solution.  I'm still not entirely clear exactly what you are doing or why and what your final code/config looks like.

Answer (score 0):

An error was in using users_in_memory provider instead of users.